# Firebase schedule function - Not able to deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My code:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => { console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!'); });
```

To deploy I run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:scheduledFunction
```

When trying to deploy the schedule function am getting this issue

> src/index.ts(490,18): error TS2339: Property 'schedule' does not exist on type 'typeof "/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions...'

Comment: Hello, you should share your entire Cloud Function code for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pubsub.schedule()` trigger was added in [version 2.3 of the `firebase-functions` library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v2.3.0). Most likely you're using a version older than that.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your reply and will check this

Comment: Thanks frank. It works after upgrading to 2.3 of firebase functions and firebase admin and typescript version